# VB.NET Read text file line by line and set every line in textbox with button clicks

Tags: vb.net

hello i want to read text file line by line and set every lien in textbox eash time i click the  button 
this is my code and working fine. but i looking for easy way to read large text that has more thean 5 lines ?

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Static count As Integer
    count = count + 1

    Dim textfile As String = "c:\test.txt"
    If IO.File.Exists(textfile) Then
        Dim readLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
        If count = 1 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(0)
        End If
        If count = 2 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(1)
        End If
        If count = 3 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(2)
        End If
        If count = 4 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(3)
        End If
        If count = 5 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(4)
        End If
        If count = 6 Then
            TextBox1.Text = readLines(5)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: open the file outside the event and maintain a reference to the stream; then dont ReadAllLines, but read a single line each time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to read the file just one time when you load your form (assuming a WinForms example here)

```
' Declare these two globally 
Dim readLines() As String
Dim count As Integer = 0

Private void Form_Load(sender As Oject, e As EventArgs) Handles Base.Load

    ' In form load, read the file, just one time
    Dim textfile As String = "c:\test.txt"
    If IO.File.Exists(textfile) Then
        readLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
    else 
        TextBox1.Text "File not found"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    ' Check if you have a file and if you don't have reached the last line
    if readLines IsNot Nothing AndAlso count < readLines.Length Then
        TextBox1.Text = readLines(count)
        count += 1
    else 
        TextBox1.Text "End of file"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This reduces the amount of code you need to write:

```
TextBox1.Text = readLines(count - 1)
```