# Vb.net Get the text from Textbox inserted line by line in other Textboxes

Tags: vb.net

[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOllx.png)I made a program that gives the user the possibility to insert text into text boxes and then it gets saved as a Text-file. Now I want to give the user a possibility to read the values from file back to the Text boxes. I though about importing the whole text into a big multi-line-textbox( I called it "mothertext") and from there import it into other textboxes..
I think about something that works like:

```
textbox1.text = mothertext.text.line (1)
textbox2.text = mothertext.text.line (2)
textbox3.text = mothertext.text.line (3)
```

Is there a way that works that way or similar?
Thanks a lot if you can help me :)

"Für später speichern"= Save for later/later editing
"Öffnen"= Open( *.txt file)

> Thats the last function, seems so easy but... yah

Comment: What you've tried so far ??,show a sample contents in that text file and the code used to save the texts to a text file

Comment: mothertext.text returns one big string, not an array of lines. You will to use a string "split" function to break up the string using the "new line" character as the delimiter. Something like: Dim aryLines As String() = Split(mothertext.text, vbCrLf)  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I tried this way "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046853/vb-net-read-text-file-line-by-line-and-set-every-line-in-textbox-with-button-cli"
But its not that what I need.
It should be easy but I will try the hard way to, I need only some tips :)

Comment: Ok I will try that @modal_dialog

Comment: I tried but I did some error with the syntax, can @modal_dialog please help me with it?

Comment: The link you referenced yourself is already the easy way to do it - how can it get more easy? :D

Comment: OK I edited it and now everything works fine ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Static count As Integer
    count = count + 1
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls"
    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        Dim read As IO.StreamReader
        read = IO.File.OpenText(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox17.Text = read.ReadToEnd()
        read.Close()
        Dim readLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        TextBox1.Text = readLines(0)
```